# Python sqlite user input search

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to get the IDs of the films from DB where category equals users input category, but for some reason I'm not able to do it.
My code:

```
import sqlite3

#Connectin to DB
conn = sqlite3.connect('sakila.db')
c = conn.cursor()

#Checking if the connection to the DB is successful
if (conn):
    print("Connection successful")
else:
    print ("Connection unsuccessful")

kategorija=input("Enter the category: ")
c.execute("SELECT FID FROM film_list WHERE category=%s", (kategorija,))
film = c.fetchall()
#Removing duplicates
final_film = list(dict.fromkeys(film))
print(final_film)
```

The error i get: line 14, in 
c.execute("SELECT FID FROM film_list WHERE category=%s", (kategorija,))
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error

Comment: The parameter placeholder used by sqlite is `?`, not `%s`.  Your query should be `SELECT FID FROM film_list WHERE category=?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can get [here](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/sqlite-python-select/) the way to bind python variables to sqlite queries is `?`

```py
priority = input("Enter priority : ")
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE priority=?", (priority,))
rows = cur.fetchall()
```

If you want to remove duplicates you could consider changing your query to

```
SELECT DISTINCT ...
```

This will change the behavior of sql to only select distinct values (i think this is obvious).

Comment: This is really useful, thank you!